# Creating JSON out of string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to get JSON similar to this

```
{
"Name": "xxxxx",
"ApplicationId": "xxxxx",
"Features": [
  {
     "Name": "xxxxx",
     "Code": "xxxxx",
  }
 ]
}
```

and my code is so far is

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
       new {
            Name = name ,
            ApplicationId = applicationID ,
            Features = (new[]{feature_name , feature_code})
           }, Formatting.None);
```

I can not figure out the feature part, it won't get created as in the example.
I read so many post, but did not find anything about inner objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't give the features appropriate names, hence then variable names are used.

Use this instead:

```
new[] { new { Name = feature_name, Code = feature_code } }
```

Also, you have to supply a list of features, for example using LINQ.

```
features.Select(f => new { Name = f.feature_name, Code = f.feature_code })
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this can be like:

```
var createJson = new {
    Name = "xxxxx",
    ApplicationId = "xxxxx",
    Features = new[] {
      new  { Name = "xxxxx", Code = "xxxxx" },
      new  { Name = "xxxxx", Code = "xxxxx" }
    }
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(createjson, Formatting.Indented);
```